# Multiple Dynamic Canvases in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

For a website I'm making I'm going to need multiple canvases that make a ring around individual images.

I've experimented with HTML, CSS, and JS in JSfiddle and have managed to create the desired effect I want with a single image, but when I duplicate the html it doesn't make a second canvas (or maybe it's making another, just the same place as the first?)

https://jsfiddle.net/impo/87e8yqnt/23/

Above is my jsfiddle, how would I change it so that every image is with its canvas?

```js
   var canvas = document.getElementById('border');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = 58;
      var y = 58;
      var radius = 55;
      var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
      var endAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise = false;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.lineWidth = 3;

      // line color
      context.strokeStyle = '#ebebeb';
      context.stroke();
      
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
      
      context.lineWidth = 4;
      context.strokeStyle = '#8aff92';
      context.stroke();
```

```css
.pkmn 
{
 position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 116px;
  height: 116px;
}

.pkmn .sprite
{
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.pkmn .lvl
{
 font-family: 'Courier New Regular', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
    margin-top:0;
}

.pkmn .crown
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 44px;
  bottom: 9px;
}

.pkmn .item
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 12px;
}

.pkmn .star
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 14px;
}

.pkmn .heart {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 40px;
}

.pkmn .exp {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pkmn">
    <canvas id="border" class="exp" width="115" height="115"></canvas>

    <div class="lvl">95</div>
    
    <img alt="test" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/76/Spr_5b_143_s.png" class="sprite">
    <img alt="item" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/0/0f/Bag_Leftovers_Sprite.png" class="item">
    <img alt="crown" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" class="crown">
    <img alt="star" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/27/ShinyVIStar.png" class="star">
    <img alt="heart" src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s519/impojr/heart_zpsdaihll9m.png" class="heart">
</div>

<div class="pkmn">
    <canvas id="border" class="exp" width="115" height="115"></canvas>

    <div class="lvl">95</div>
    
    <img alt="test" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/76/Spr_5b_143_s.png" class="sprite">
    <img alt="item" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/0/0f/Bag_Leftovers_Sprite.png" class="item">
    <img alt="crown" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" class="crown">
    <img alt="star" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/27/ShinyVIStar.png" class="star">
    <img alt="heart" src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s519/impojr/heart_zpsdaihll9m.png" class="heart">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Warning Quirks Mode.

Don`t use duplicated ID's this will cause your page to slow down and many behaviors to change due to the fact the browser switches to [quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode).

I add this answer for that reason and because the given answer has another very bad bit of code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.border').length; i++) {  
      var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('#border')[i];
```

This code does 2 document queries for every item found by the query. This would noticeably slow the page with just a few dozen matching elements on low end machines.

```js
const canvases = document.querySelectorAll('.exp')
for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {  
      var canvas = canvases[i];
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = 58;
      var y = 58;
      var radius = 55;
      var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
      var endAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise = false;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.lineWidth = 3;

      // line color
      context.strokeStyle = '#ebebeb';
      context.stroke();
      
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
      
      context.lineWidth = 4;
      context.strokeStyle = '#8aff92';
      context.stroke();
}
```

```css
.pkmn 
{
 position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 116px;
  height: 116px;
}

.pkmn .sprite
{
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.pkmn .lvl
{
 font-family: 'Courier New Regular', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
    margin-top:0;
}

.pkmn .crown
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 44px;
  bottom: 9px;
}

.pkmn .item
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 12px;
}

.pkmn .star
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 14px;
}

.pkmn .heart {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 40px;
}

.pkmn .exp {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pkmn">
    <canvas id="border1" class="exp" width="115" height="115"></canvas>

    <div class="lvl">95</div>
    
    <img alt="test" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/76/Spr_5b_143_s.png" class="sprite">
    <img alt="item" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/0/0f/Bag_Leftovers_Sprite.png" class="item">
    <img alt="crown" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" class="crown">
    <img alt="star" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/27/ShinyVIStar.png" class="star">
    <img alt="heart" src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s519/impojr/heart_zpsdaihll9m.png" class="heart">
</div>

<div class="pkmn">
    <canvas id="border2" class="exp" width="115" height="115"></canvas>

    <div class="lvl">95</div>
    
    <img alt="test" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/76/Spr_5b_143_s.png" class="sprite">
    <img alt="item" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/0/0f/Bag_Leftovers_Sprite.png" class="item">
    <img alt="crown" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" class="crown">
    <img alt="star" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/27/ShinyVIStar.png" class="star">
    <img alt="heart" src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s519/impojr/heart_zpsdaihll9m.png" class="heart">
</div>
```

Comment: read up a little on the difference between class and id - should have been obvious! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in for loop which goes through all the elements having id border. Below is modified code.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#border').length; i++) {  
      var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('#border')[i];
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = 58;
      var y = 58;
      var radius = 55;
      var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
      var endAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise = false;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.lineWidth = 3;

      // line color
      context.strokeStyle = '#ebebeb';
      context.stroke();
      
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
      
      context.lineWidth = 4;
      context.strokeStyle = '#8aff92';
      context.stroke();
}
```

```css
.pkmn 
{
 position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 116px;
  height: 116px;
}

.pkmn .sprite
{
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.pkmn .lvl
{
 font-family: 'Courier New Regular', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
    margin-top:0;
}

.pkmn .crown
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 44px;
  bottom: 9px;
}

.pkmn .item
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 12px;
}

.pkmn .star
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 14px;
}

.pkmn .heart {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 40px;
}

.pkmn .exp {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pkmn">
    <canvas id="border" class="exp" width="115" height="115"></canvas>

    <div class="lvl">95</div>
    
    <img alt="test" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/76/Spr_5b_143_s.png" class="sprite">
    <img alt="item" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/0/0f/Bag_Leftovers_Sprite.png" class="item">
    <img alt="crown" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" class="crown">
    <img alt="star" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/27/ShinyVIStar.png" class="star">
    <img alt="heart" src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s519/impojr/heart_zpsdaihll9m.png" class="heart">
</div>

<div class="pkmn">
    <canvas id="border" class="exp" width="115" height="115"></canvas>

    <div class="lvl">95</div>
    
    <img alt="test" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/7/76/Spr_5b_143_s.png" class="sprite">
    <img alt="item" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/0/0f/Bag_Leftovers_Sprite.png" class="item">
    <img alt="crown" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" class="crown">
    <img alt="star" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/2/27/ShinyVIStar.png" class="star">
    <img alt="heart" src="http://i1055.photobucket.com/albums/s519/impojr/heart_zpsdaihll9m.png" class="heart">
</div>
```

Use document.querySelectorAll() for getting all the elements having the id border.

Comment: I agree, but it's better not to use the same ID multiple times. Therefore, you have to use classes.

Comment: I knew it would be something to do with my JS! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry but you should never use the same ID ID must be unique .If not unique the browser  will be place in quirks mode slowing the whole page down and changing many behaviors. A far better solution is to use `querySelectorAll(".exp")` to find the canvas elements via the class name and remove the duplicated ID's completely.

Comment: you r right. i knew it can affect performance. But in his question he didn't have a class